# How to insert HTML code via Tag Manager - non developer

Tags: google-tag-manager

I am not a developer so please bear with me. I am trying to install the Google Tag Manager plugin on my website that runs on Craft CRM.

The plugin is asking me to do two things:

Copy the code below and paste it into you layout as high as possible in the  section of the page:

`{{ craft.googleTagManager.headSection() }}`

You must also paste this code immediately after the opening tag :

`{{ craft.googleTagManager.bodySection() }}`

I tried creating a Custom HTML in Google Tag Manager and I get the following error:

Unknown variable “ craft.googleTagManager.headSection() ” found in a tag. Edit the tag and remove the reference to the unknown variable.

Any help is really appreciated

Comment: Post the surrounding HTML, where exactly did you paste the code?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. surrounding HTML? The plugin instructions only asks me to place the code. I am using the Tag Manager All page trigger

https://ibb.co/zbnnKWV

Answer (score 1):

You are mistaken on the instructions. You need to copy and paste that code for craft CMS, not doing it in GTM.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Don't quite understand: Does that mean I can't inject the craft code via GTM?

Comment: No you can't because GTM needs a code snippet put on the page as well.